# Spring, inject properties in a Bean instance based one of that Bean's field value, is it possible?

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, javabeans

I have a Pojo I use to configure webservices' clients:

```
public class ServiceConfig {

    private String url;
    private String endpoint;
    private String serviceName;

    public ServiceConfig(String serviceName) {
        super();
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }
```

}

Now, this is what my application.properties file looks like:

```
service1.url=http://localhost:8087/
service1.endpoint=SOME_ENDPOIT1
service2.url=http://localhost:8085/
service2.endpoint=SOME_ENDPOIT2
service3.url=http://localhost:8086/
service3.endpoint=SOME_ENDPOIT3
service4.url=http://localhost:8088/
service4.endpoint=SOME_ENDPOIT4
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for Spring to inject the correct properties when I instantiate ServiceConfig like this:

ServiceConfig sc = new ServiceConfig("service1");

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using just spring or also spring-boot?

What about injecting `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` to your pojo and configuring it with it.

so something like this could work:

```
public class ServiceConfig {

    private String url;
    private String endpoint;
    private String serviceName;

    public ServiceConfig(String serviceName, Environment env) {
        // TODO assert on serviceName not empty 
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.url = env.getProperty(serviceName.concat(".url");
        this.endpoint = env.getProperty(serviceName.concat(".endpoint"); 
    }
}
```

I guess there could be a simpler/more elegant solution, but I don't know your case.

**spring-boot version**

well with spring boot just define your pojo (field names must match property names)

```
public class ServiceConfig {

    private String url;
    private String endpoint;

    // getters setters
}
```

and then in some configuration you can do this (note: value in `ConfigurationProperties` is prefix of your configuration in `application.properties`):

```
@Configuration
public class ServicesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("service1")
    ServiceConfig service1(){
        return new ServiceConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("service2")
    ServiceConfig service2(){
        return new ServiceConfig();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that works! Thanks! I'm using Spring Boot, does it make a difference?

Comment: I've edited the answer, consider what is better for you.